# DataTable RowFilter custom distinct

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, datatable, dataset, dataview

I have a column with dates in my DataTable using C#. Something like this:

2014/06/26 11:23 AM
2014/06/26 11:45 AM
2014/06/26 12:23 AM
2014/06/27 01:30 PM
2014/06/27 01:50 PM
2014/06/27 02:30 PM
2014/06/29 04:00 PM
2014/06/29 05:30 PM
2014/06/29 06:15 PM

If I do this: MyDataView.ToTable(true, MyDateField)... then I get ALL the dates above since they are all unique.

What I want to do is get distinct based off the date part only ignoring the time part completely.

The result I'm looking for out of the dates above is:

2014/06/26
2014/06/27
2014/06/29

It has to happen in my DataTable for this project. Usually I would do all these things in SQL before the data even gets to the app, but here I have no choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DataView.ToTable(true, "DateColumn")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.110).aspx) returns distinct DateTime values as expected.

To filter out records on the basis of date part you could select distinct rows from datatable like this:

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => ((DateTime)r["DateColumn"]).Date).Distinct();

foreach (var row in rows)
{

}
```

or

```
DataTable distinctTable = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .GroupBy(r => r.Field<DateTime>("DateColumn").Date)
                       .Select(g => g.First())
                       .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks. I marked this as the answer since this worked for me, although handling potential nulls in the linq took me a little to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
dates.Select(x => new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, x.Day)).Distinct()
```

see demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WBvI1c

Comment: Or even `dates.Select(x => x.Date).Distinct()`

Comment: OP requires filter to be applied on datatable